# Java Quicksort how to swap middle element with pivot

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I am trying to implement the quicksort algorithm using Java. I have created my partition function as follows:

```
int [] quickPartition(int[] array, int low, int high){

    int  pivot = array[low], end_mark = high, start_mark = 1, temp;

    while (start_mark != end_mark) {
        if (array[start_mark] > pivot) {
            while (end_mark != start_mark) {
                if (array[end_mark] < pivot) {
                    temp = array[end_mark];
                    array[end_mark] = array[start_mark];
                    array[start_mark] = temp;

                    break;
                }
                end_mark--;
            }
        }
        start_mark++;
    }

    return array;
}
```

`array[low]` is my pivot, `end_mark` is the last element of the array and start_mark is the first element after pivot

The first while loop loops from the start towards the end looking for the next number larger than the pivot. When found, the second loop starts from the end of the array towards the start looking for the next number smaller than the pivot. If both of these conditions are satisfied, swapping occurs. 
However, if the both the looping indices(startindex and endindex) meet, the while loops exit.

Sample array: [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 90, 31, 44, 55, 20]
Returned:     [54, 26, 20, 17, 44, 31, 90, 77, 55, 93]

As you can see, the relevant elements have been partitioned. However, the last step involves swapping the pivot(54) and (31), So that all elements greater than 54 are on the right and those less than 54 are on the left. How do you swap 31 and 54 yet at this point(where start_index == end_index)  the while loop has already stopped? Take note that if you swap outside the while loops the value 31 will be lost.

Comment: Your code seems logically wrong. Note that merge sort requires that at least one element should be in its proper place after each iteration. Your code will never swap 55 since it is always greater than 54 which is the pivot. You need to change your pivot after each iteration!

Comment: van Emden improved on quicksort  in 1970 by choosing the middle from lowest, highest and median value as the pivot instead of just lowest.  Your code is nearly 50 years out of date.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the outer while loop, array[start_mark] will be the first number >= than the pivot, so you should swap the pivot with array[start_mark-1].

Also, this code will produce an ArrayOutOfBoundsException if the pivot is the minimum value in the array: end_mark would decrease until end_mark == start_mark == 1.
Then start_mark would become 2, and the outer while loop condition won't be met.
Setting the condition of the outer while loop to start_mark<=end_mark should fix this.
The code would look like this

```
int  pivot = array[low], end_mark = high, start_mark = 1, temp;
while (start_mark < end_mark) {
    if (array[start_mark] > pivot) {
        while (end_mark != start_mark) {
            if (array[end_mark] < pivot) {
                temp = array[end_mark];
                array[end_mark] = array[start_mark];
                array[start_mark] = temp;

                break;
            }
            end_mark--;
        }
    }
    start_mark++;
}
temp = array[start_mark-1];
array[start_mark-1] = pivot;
array[low] = temp;
return array;
```

Comment: Not Working! Array remains unsorted

Comment: Unpartitioned array: [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 90, 31, 44, 55, 20]
Partitioned  array:   [90, 26, 20, 17, 44, 31, 54, 77, 55, 93]            It is not 90 to be swapped with 54; but 31 which ought to be swapped

Comment: Changed ">=" with "<" in the outer while loop

Comment: So that as soon as start_mark==end_mark the while loop ends.
Like this we can obtain the conditions described in the original answer

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate that you want to learn fom your mistakes, so I will not give you the solution, but the steps in each iteration. Note that merge sort requires that at least one element should be in its proper sorted place after every iteration.

STEP1: If you are sorting in ascending order and your pivot is the first element, then your first pointer (say, i) needs to find the element **lesser** than the pivot (all elements equal to or greater than the pivot should be to the right of the pivot)

STEP2: When you find the first element lesser than the pivot (pointed by i), you need to iterate from i+1 to high (call the iterator pointer j) and swap array[i] with every element less than i.

STEP3: Swap the pivot with i.

At the end of step3 (one iteration), the element previously pointed by i (now pointed by the pivot) is in its proper sorted place. In this case, the pivot will be at index 0 and this will contain the least element of the array.

Repeat these steps i.e. call your quickpartition function again, but now for low=1

The issue with your code is that you never swap your pivot. Also, you never try to find the **least element greater than the pivot**, which is what step 2 does. You simply find **one element greater than the pivot**

Comment: Actually my question is pretty much about swapping the pivot....but I kind of think our interpretation of quicksort is different... [check out this link] (https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheQuickSort.html)